# How to pass ID to controller?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/${id}">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="${id}" placeholder="Input Id">
    <button>Get User</button>
</form>
```

How to pass id to controller?

```
    @RequestMapping (value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getStudent(@PathVariable ("id") Integer id, Model model){
        User savedUser = userRepository.get(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", savedUser);
        return "user";
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Here, you're sending it in the URL and as a request parameter.

Comment: My controller didn't get request.

Comment: So the problem is with your configuration.

Comment: Or a omitted context path

Comment: I don't think so because when I change my jsp file to `<form method="POST" action="/user/1">` it works fine.

Comment: It seams that my form is wrong (maybe in input).

Comment: Have you added a request attribute named `id` before rendering that view that contains the `form`?

Comment: Do you get a 400 Bad Request?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm getting 404. And my path is http://localhost/user, not http://localhost/user/[number].

Answer (score 1):

You could do this way , consider i am passing the `${id}` value through the query string

```
<a href="user?id=${id}">Get User</a>
```

And in your controller,

```
@RequestMapping ("user")
    public String getStudent(@RequestParam  Integer id, Model model){
        User savedUser = userRepository.get(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", savedUser);
        return "user";
    }
```

Hope this helps !